# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: hibernate, struts2, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a form in which there is a text field. The user inputs the email address in the text field, and when the user submits the form, the `Action` class finds the `uid` of the user from the `Users` table and displays the `uid` on the JSP page as a message with `<s:actionmessage/>`. I am getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

My JSP form is:

```
<s:form action="okadddqs" method="post" cssClass="text">

   <s:textfield label="Your Email address " name="email"/>
   <s:submit value="Find Uid"/>
 </s:form>
```

The code for the `Action` class is:

```
package com.rambo.action;

import beans.Users;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.hibernate.Session;

/**
 *
 * @author ROMO
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class NewQuestion extends ActionSupport {

    private String email;

    private List<Users> ul = new ArrayList<Users>();

    public List<Users> getUl() {
        return ul;
    }

    public void setUl(List<Users> ul) {
        this.ul = ul;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
/* i have used many where the getUid() and getEmail() even in the error and messages to find what the value it is getting on error.  */
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        Session session = null;
        int d;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            try {
                ul = (List<Users>) session.createQuery("from Users c where c.email = '" + getEmail() + "'");
                if (!ul.isEmpty()) {
                    d = ul.get(0).getUid();
                } else {
                    this.addActionError("Oops. Sorry. You are Not Allowed now. Please Try Again Later." + getEmail() + ","+ ul.get(0).getUid());
                    session.close();
                    return ERROR;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.addActionError("Oops. There was an error." + getEmail() + ","+ ul.get(0).getUid());
                session.close();
                return ERROR;
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.addActionError("Oops. An Error Encountered...! Email address " + getEmail() + ","+ ul.get(0).getUid()+" not registered. Try with your new email address.");
            session.close();
            return ERROR;
        }
        this.addActionMessage("Your Uid is : " + ul.get(0).getUid());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

   @Override
    public void validate() {
       if ( "".equals(getEmail()) || getEmail() == null ) {
            this.addActionError("Email is Compulsory to input..!" + getCname());
        } else if (getEmail().indexOf("@") < 0 || getEmail().indexOf(",") > 0 || getEmail().indexOf(".") < 0 || lastEmailFieldTwoCharsOrMore(getEmail()) == false) {
            this.addActionError("Please Input a valid email address." + getCname());
        }
    }
}
```

when i remove all the try catch blocks i get the exception as :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

I have done the beans and mapping of tables properly with POJO. Can someone point out the error? I am using Hibernate with Struts.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace about that exception.

Comment: sorry but infact i am not getting any stacktrace of errors on the glassfish server logs. However the only exception is seen on the browser.

Comment: It's because you're catching the exception using `try...catch`. Temporarily comment this `try...catch` and you will get the stack trace. It's only because someone can better guess the exact cause of the exception only after he/she views the stack trace.

Comment: yes i am doing the same right now. wait a seconds i put the stack trace.

Comment: Oops i again dont get any stack trace of errors. But now exception is changed to "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line in your code is incorrect:

```
ul = (List<Users>) session.createQuery(
    "from Users c where c.email = '" + getEmail() + "'"
);
```

[createQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html) returns back a query object. If you want the results of that query, use [Query.list()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29).

```
ul = (List<Users>) session.createQuery(
    "from Users c where c.email = '" + getEmail() + "'"
).list();
```